# Android can't allow notifications for my app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have FCM set up for my application, and my server is able to send notifications to my device, on the server end it says success but the device isn't receiving anything.

The notifications were working about a week ago but since uninstalling/reinstalling the app they stopped.

I assumed it was because I needed to allow notification from the app settings, which I used to have an option to do, but now when I go to the app settings I see no option to enable notification...

[image: Settings]

Is there something I need to add to make the setting show up again?